# PostgreSQL 12 problem restoring from pg_basebackup on CentOS8

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql, postgresql-12

I have recently created a Postgres backup, and attempted to use this backup, at which point I recieve the following error, when I try to start the server with - start postgresql-12.service, I get
:

```
Job for postgresql-12.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postgresql-12.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl

```
[lloyd@localhost lib]$ systemctl status postgresql-12.service
● postgresql-12.service - PostgreSQL 12 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-12.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-11-10 12:56:14 GMT; 2min 3s ago
     Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/static/
  Process: 5124 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-12/bin/postgresql-12-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 12 database server...
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: cat: /var/lib/pgsql/12/data//PG_VERSION: Permission denied
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: cat: /var/lib/pgsql/12/data//PG_VERSION: Permission denied
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: An old version of the database format was found.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: You need to dump and reload before using PostgreSQL 12.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: See /usr/share/doc/postgresql12/README.rpm-dist for more informa>
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-12.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-12.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 12 database server.
lines 1-15/15 (END)
```

journalctl -xe

```
[lloyd@localhost lib]$ journalctl -xe
-- Subject: Unit fprintd.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit fprintd.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain polkitd[946]: Operator of unix-session:8 successfully authenticated as unix-user:lloyd to gain TEM>
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 12 database server...
-- Subject: Unit postgresql-12.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit postgresql-12.service has begun starting up.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: cat: /var/lib/pgsql/12/data//PG_VERSION: Permission denied
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: cat: /var/lib/pgsql/12/data//PG_VERSION: Permission denied
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: An old version of the database format was found.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: You need to dump and reload before using PostgreSQL 12.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: See /usr/share/doc/postgresql12/README.rpm-dist for more informa>
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-12.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-12.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 12 database server.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql-12.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit postgresql-12.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost.localdomain polkitd[946]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:5092:130783 (system bus name :1.9>
lines 1356-1385/1385 (END)
```

I have created a directory to store my Postgres backups to located here: /tmp/backups/

I created the backup like so:

```
pg_basebackup -D /tmp/backups -h localhost --checkpoint=fast --wal-method=stream
```

I then stopped the server like so:

```
systemctl stop postgresql-12.service
```

moved the files that were located here:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/12/data
```

to another backup folder: `/tmp/backups_archive1`

I then moved the files that were backed up here: `/tmp/backups/` and copied them to: `/var/lib/pgsql/12/data`

I then attempt to start the server:

```
systemctl start postgresql-12.service
```

and recieve this error:

```
[lloyd@localhost /]$ sudo systemctl start postgres-12.service
Failed to start postgres-12.service: Unit postgres-12.service not found.
```

I also tried:

```
[lloyd@localhost /]$ sudo service postgres-12.service reload
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl reload postgres-12.service
Failed to reload postgres-12.service: Unit postgres-12.service not found.
```

Any guidance as to why I am recieve this error would be greatly appreciated.

### Thanks,
Lloyd

var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

var/lib/pgsql/12/data/postgresql.conf
changes made to this file include:

```
archive_mode = on
restore_command = 'cp /archive/%f %p'
recovery_target_time = '2020-11-10 10:10:10'
wal_level = replica 
max_wal_senders = 10
```

You will notice that I have my WAL files archived here too:

```
[lloyd@localhost /]$ ls
archive  bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
[lloyd@localhost /]$ cd archive
[lloyd@localhost archive]$ ls -l
total 229396
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov  7 10:33 000000010000000000000003
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov  7 10:33 000000010000000000000004
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres      337 Nov  7 10:33 000000010000000000000004.00000028.backup
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov  7 10:33 000000010000000000000005
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov  7 10:33 000000010000000000000006
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres      337 Nov  7 10:33 000000010000000000000006.00000028.backup
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov  7 10:33 000000010000000000000007
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov  7 10:33 000000010000000000000008
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres      337 Nov  7 10:33 000000010000000000000008.00000028.backup
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov  7 10:33 000000010000000000000009
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov  7 10:33 00000001000000000000000A
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres      337 Nov  7 10:33 00000001000000000000000A.00000028.backup
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 11:22 00000001000000000000000B
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 11:34 00000001000000000000000C
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 11:35 00000001000000000000000D
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 11:37 00000001000000000000000E
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 11:37 00000001000000000000000F
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres      337 Nov 10 11:37 00000001000000000000000F.00000028.backup
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 10 11:48 000000010000000000000010
[lloyd@localhost archive]$
```

/var/log/messages/

```
Nov 10 12:56:12 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Nov 10 12:56:12 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Nov 10 12:56:12 localhost systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 12 database server...
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: cat: /var/lib/pgsql/12/data//PG_VERSION: Permission denied
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: cat: /var/lib/pgsql/12/data//PG_VERSION: Permission denied
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: An old version of the database format was found.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: You need to dump and reload before using PostgreSQL 12.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost postgresql-12-check-db-dir[5124]: See /usr/share/doc/postgresql12/README.rpm-dist for more information.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost systemd[1]: postgresql-12.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost systemd[1]: postgresql-12.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 10 12:56:14 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 12 database server.
Nov 10 13:05:09 localhost dbus-daemon[3086]: [session uid=1000 pid=3086] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.19' (uid=1000 pid=3232 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:05:09 localhost dbus-daemon[3086]: [session uid=1000 pid=3086] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Nov 10 13:05:10 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.1005' (uid=1000 pid=5305 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:05:10 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Nov 10 13:05:10 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Nov 10 13:05:10 localhost systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Nov 10 13:05:37 localhost kernel: capability: warning: `gvfsd-admin' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
Nov 10 13:05:37 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.1017' (uid=0 pid=5362 comm="/usr/lib/polkit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 lloyd " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:05:37 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Nov 10 13:05:38 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Nov 10 13:05:38 localhost systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Nov 10 13:05:47 localhost dbus-daemon[3086]: [session uid=1000 pid=3086] Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit' requested by ':1.97' (uid=1000 pid=5305 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:05:47 localhost dbus-daemon[3086]: [session uid=1000 pid=3086] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'
Nov 10 13:05:48 localhost journal[5450]: The specified location is not mounted
Nov 10 13:06:12 localhost journal[3411]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-default: unable to get EDID for output
Nov 10 13:06:26 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.1123' (uid=0 pid=5509 comm="sudo service postgres-12.service reload " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:06:26 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Nov 10 13:06:26 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Nov 10 13:06:26 localhost systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Nov 10 13:14:09 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.1142' (uid=0 pid=5663 comm="sudo systemctl start postgres-12.service " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:14:09 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Nov 10 13:14:09 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Nov 10 13:14:09 localhost systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Nov 10 13:15:45 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.1149' (uid=0 pid=5760 comm="sudo service postgres-12.service reload " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:15:45 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Nov 10 13:15:46 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Nov 10 13:15:46 localhost systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Nov 10 13:16:34 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.807' (uid=1000 pid=3893 comm="/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:16:34 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Nov 10 13:16:34 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Nov 10 13:16:34 localhost systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Nov 10 13:18:26 localhost dbus-daemon[3086]: [session uid=1000 pid=3086] Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit' requested by ':1.97' (uid=1000 pid=5305 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:18:26 localhost dbus-daemon[3086]: [session uid=1000 pid=3086] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'
Nov 10 13:19:31 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.1005' (uid=1000 pid=5305 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:19:31 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Nov 10 13:19:32 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Nov 10 13:19:32 localhost systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Nov 10 13:19:49 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.1161' (uid=0 pid=5912 comm="/usr/lib/polkit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 lloyd " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:19:49 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Nov 10 13:19:49 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Nov 10 13:19:49 localhost systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Nov 10 13:20:37 localhost journal[5869]: The specified location is not mounted
Nov 10 13:20:37 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.1234' (uid=0 pid=6020 comm="/usr/lib/polkit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 lloyd " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:20:37 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Nov 10 13:20:37 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Nov 10 13:20:37 localhost systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Nov 10 13:23:01 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.807' (uid=1000 pid=3893 comm="/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Nov 10 13:23:01 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Nov 10 13:23:02 localhost dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Nov 10 13:23:02 localhost systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
```

/var/log/secure

```
Nov 10 13:14:11 localhost sudo[5663]:   lloyd : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/lib ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start postgres-12.service
Nov 10 13:14:12 localhost sudo[5663]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session or user slice
Nov 10 13:14:12 localhost sudo[5663]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 10 13:14:12 localhost sudo[5663]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 10 13:14:31 localhost sudo[5691]:   lloyd : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start postgres-12.service
Nov 10 13:14:31 localhost sudo[5691]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session or user slice
Nov 10 13:14:31 localhost sudo[5691]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 10 13:14:31 localhost sudo[5691]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 10 13:15:48 localhost sudo[5760]:   lloyd : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/var/lib ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/service postgres-12.service reload
Nov 10 13:15:48 localhost sudo[5760]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session or user slice
Nov 10 13:15:48 localhost sudo[5760]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 10 13:15:48 localhost sudo[5760]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 10 13:15:55 localhost sudo[5791]:   lloyd : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/service postgres-12.service reload
Nov 10 13:15:55 localhost sudo[5791]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session or user slice
Nov 10 13:15:55 localhost sudo[5791]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 10 13:15:55 localhost sudo[5791]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 10 13:19:52 localhost polkitd[946]: Operator of unix-session:8 successfully authenticated as unix-user:lloyd to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.gtk.vfs.file-operations for unix-process:5305:184555 [/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service] (owned by unix-user:lloyd)
Nov 10 13:20:40 localhost polkitd[946]: Operator of unix-session:8 successfully authenticated as unix-user:lloyd to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.gtk.vfs.file-operations for unix-process:5869:264271 [/usr/bin/gedit --gapplication-service] (owned by unix-user:lloyd)
```

Comment: why is it complaining about this? `cat: /var/lib/pgsql/12/data//PG_VERSION: Permission denied` Does that file exist and is it owned by "postgres"?

Comment: Probably because of this `.../data//PG_VERSION`, doubled `/`.